# Is it possible to stop a Timer (System.Timers.Timer) from inside the OnTimedEvent Method

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to make a countdown function which would stop when the timer reaches 0. What is happening so far is that when the timer reaches 0 (and I haven't pressed any key) it keeps spamming me with the default message and it doesn't stop until I click a button.

I would like to insert some code inside `OnTimedEvent` which would stop the timer (once it hits zero, display the message and stop spamming me). I have tryed multiple variations of `aTimer.Stop` `aTimer.Enabled = false;` etc.

I get an error

> *The name 'aTimer' does not exist in the current context.*

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace MyProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread still running");
            Console.WriteLine("Press X to save the world.");
            Console.WriteLine("You have 10 SECONDS!");

            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;


            ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey(true);

            switch (input.KeyChar)
            {
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Blah blah");
                    aTimer.Enabled = false;
                    break;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static int _countDown = 10; // Seconds
        private static bool dMade = false;

        static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dMade == false)
            {
                if (_countDown-- <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have doomed us all! DOOMED US ALL I TELL YOU!!!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                    Console.ForegroundColor
                        = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write(_countDown + " ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor
                        = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success! The world is saved. Congrats!");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an error The name 'aTimer' does not exist in the current
> context.

This is because the aTimer is not in scope in the OnTimedEvent method. The scope of the aTimer is in the Main method because that is where it is declared.
If you move the aTimer to a static field inside the Program class instead of a local variable it will be in scope for all the methods in it:

```
class Program
    {
        static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread still running");
            Console.WriteLine("Press X to save the world.");
            Console.WriteLine("You have 10 SECONDS!");

            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

...
```

Then you can reference aTimer in your OnTimedEvent method.

```
static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           aTimer.Enabled = false;
...
```

A variables scope depends on where it is declared, so if it's declared in the body of the class, all methods can access it (if it's static or the methods are not static). If a variable is declared in the scope of a method, it's only visible to that method (from the point it's declared up until the closing brace '}' for that method.

Comment: I've added medifeid the code as suggested and it does stop the timer. But now I get an error or `aTimer.Enabled = false;` -> *Exception User-Unhandled ... System.NullRefernceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*.

Comment: @DrDoom did you change the instantiation line to use the field instead of a local variable declaration: 
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

Comment: No. Didn't see that change. Thank you that solved it.

Comment: No problem. You had two variables in two scopes then, both called aTimer. Just for your info, if you wanted to access the aTimer declared in the body of the class you would have had to do 'this.aTimer'. :)

Answer (score 3):

In `OnTimedEvent`, the `object source` is your timer. You can stop it with the following line:

```
((System.Timers.Timer) source).Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you elaborate just a little? ie. show where exactly this is supposed to be inserted (show a bit more code for orientation)

Comment: @DrDoom - You can use that line wherever you want to stop your timer inside the `OnTimedEvent` event. To me, it's not clear from your code at what location within there that you'd want to stop it. `source` is within scope anywhere inside `OnTimedEvent`, so it's really up to you where it goes.

Comment: oh. So I don't need to append it to anything. It's a stand alone then. Thank you. I don't know why this would work. Could you direct to an appropriate Microsoft page, so I can  do some reading why/how this should work.

Comment: @DrDoom it works because it's standard for the object that the event belongs to to be the `source` parameter. It's the same as if you want to access a `TextBox` in a `TextChanged` event, for example. Unfortunately the documentation for `Timer.Elapsed` doesn't make this clear...